# How can we split a complex string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, split

```
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="229636134720" name="Nandan Mohan Nilekani" 
     gender="M" yob="1955" house="856, 13th Main , 3rd Block" 
     loc="Koramangala" vtc="Bangalore South" po="Koramangala" 
     dist="Bangalore" state="Karnataka" pc="560034"/>
```

I want to split the above string to as

```
uid="229636134720"
name="Nandan Mohan Nilekani"
gender="M"
yob="1955"
house="856, 13th Main , 3rd Block"
loc="Koramangala"
vtc="Bangalore South"
po="Koramangala"
dist="Bangalore"
state="Karnataka"
pc="560034"
```

And i tried and  failed to do like that

Comment: Try [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) library from GitHub

Comment: "And i have tried but i was failed to do like that" is not only bad grammar, but useless, when you don't state what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050884/how-to-parse-different-type-of-xml-data-or-similar-to-xml-structure/30121615#30121615 - Check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this:

```
NSString *testString = @"<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"229636134720\" name=\"Nandan Mohan Nilekani\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1955\" house=\"856, 13th Main , 3rd Block\" loc=\"Koramangala\" vtc=\"Bangalore South\" po=\"Koramangala\" dist=\"Bangalore\" state=\"Karnataka\" pc=\"560034\"/>";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@" \\w+=\".+?\"" options:0 error:nil];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, testString.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [testString substringWithRange:result.range]);
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm

First remove

```
'<PrintLetterBarcodeData' and '/>'
```

Then replace '" ', i.e. quote-space with newline.

And hope you don't have 'val=" "', i.e. a value, which starts with a blank.

Better would be a regex, which matches word="val".